# Pass both image and numerical data to Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently looking for a way to pass multiple data types to a tensorflow CNN for classification training. Specifically, I'd like to input an image as well as depth data (distance from the camera) for the image to train the CNN in different classifications, though I'm unaware if this is possible.
Due to this being the training method, I'd also need to query the model using both image and depth data too.

If anyone knows a way to do this, or some ideas to point me in the right direction, please do share them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "depth data" here. If you're referencing the number of channels in the image, that needs to be fixed for a specific CNN model because the filters will include weights for the inputs in each channel. But you can define and train a model using the maximum number of channels and pad inputs with a lower number of channels up to that maximum.

If depth is some other type of metadata for the image (such as depth under water) then you wouldn't feed it directly to the CNN layers. You'd instead define it as a separate input, and merge it with the feature output from the CNN layers feeding into the classifier.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for not explaining! By depth data, I am referencing the distance of the subject from the camera as I am using a laser camera that can detect how far away each pixel in the image is from the camera. By your description, this would require a seperate input. As I am not too familiar with CNNs, how would I go about merging the output and seperate input?

Comment: You need to use the TensorFlow Functional API: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional The basic approach to working with the two inputs is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365346/adding-multiple-metadata-to-tflearn-cnn You use the CNN layers to process the image data as one input, then at the end of that (generally with some pooling to reduce the dimensions) Flatten the CNN feature output to a simple vector and Concatenate the distance input. Then feed the concatenated vector to one or more Dense layers to classify.